# Date issue in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date

I am using EST timezone in production mode in rails APP

`production.rb`

```
config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

Now when I insert record in table, below is query

```
INSERT INTO "service_tickets" ("service_creation_date") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["service_creation_date", 2017-05-30 00:00:00 UTC], ["created_at", 2017-05-30 10:19:52 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-05-30 10:19:52 UTC]]
```

In rails c

```
ServiceTicket.last
D, [2017-05-30T16:08:04.665199 #3431] DEBUG -- :   ServiceTicket Load    (0.5ms)  SELECT  "service_tickets".* FROM "service_tickets" WHERE "service_tickets"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "service_tickets"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<ServiceTicket id: 38, service_creation_date: "2017-05-30 00:00:00", created_at: "2017-05-30 10:19:52", updated_at: "2017-05-30 10:19:52">
```

See `service_creation_date is "2017-05-30 00:00:00"`
Now When I select only date it return one day back date

```
ServiceTicket.last.service_creation_date
D, [2017-05-30T16:09:23.259613 #3431] DEBUG -- :   ServiceTicket Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "service_tickets".* FROM "service_tickets" WHERE "service_tickets"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "service_tickets"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> Mon, 29 May 2017 20:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: Could you show how are you creating the insert? What value does `service_creation_date` have? And what is the expected output/behavior?

Comment: From frontside date is passing in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, so I am coverting this date in datetime format using `Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y").to_datetime`.

Comment: So, you insert as `EST` but it is saved as `UTC`, which is normal, since you are working with rails in `EST` and ActiveRecord in `UTC` (default) value. What is the output you are expecting? Getting it in `UTC` or `EST`?

Comment: I expect date in EST.

Comment: I convert date using `Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y").in_time_zone`, now its working.
Is it right way?

Comment: Its neither right nor wrong; its a valid solution (it works); another option could be to set AR to default to localtime, and store everything in `EST`.

Comment: I already tried with `:local` for activerecord but it was not working, that's why I use above solution.

Comment: How did you set it up?

Comment: `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`

Comment: Oh, i just added an answer (just to be sure you had it right), but if that doesn't work for you, then definitely go with `in_time_zone`, that's a good solution too!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting ActiveRecord to `local`<sup>1</sup>, that way you will use same timezone across your app and db:

1. Add this to `production.rb` (to set up only *Production* environment):

   ```
   config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
   config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
   ```
2. Restart your Rails server.

<sup>1</sup> *This will use your **sever's timezone** on the database, so, if your server is in a different timezone than the one specified in `config.time_zone`, maybe you should consider setting `config.time_zone` to the server's timezone as well.*

Comment: This will change timezone for all environment, I want to change timezone for only production environment.

Comment: @ashvin You could use the above configurarion in `production.rb`.

Comment: I was already used above configurations but it was not working.

Comment: @ashvin Did you compared against the server's timezone?